# Select Data in First Element of Multi-Dimensional Array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, location, element

Is it possible to select data in a certain location, solely based on where it's located in an array? I've tried slicing my array, but it shows information I still don't want.

http://pastebin.com/68EMCSyZ

In that array, I would only like to have [match_player_stats][84947759][5947051]'s data show. But as you can see, there is another element in the same layer, which is why splicing doesn't work. Basically, I want the first total element of [match_player_stats][84947759], in this case being [5947051]. Now don't get me wrong, I could easily do this if the numbers were static, but these numbers change based on a matchID entered- which is why I need to select based on "location" (if you will).

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried array_shift of the [match_player_stats]?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first element of an array, you can use [array_shift](http://de.php.net/manual/de/function.array-shift.php). In your case:

```
$totalFirstValue = array_shift(array_shift($arr['match_player_stats']));
```

Comment: Just curious - say I wanted the one element underneath the one I wanted (the second one). Just array shift still?

Comment: @KevinMurphy Yes, you can shift until the array runs out of values.